# Does completing Sly 1 to 100% give anything other than artistic content?

Tags: the-sly-collection, sly-cooper-thievius-raccoonus

I completed *Sly Cooper and the Thievius Raccoonus* from *The Sly Collection* (PS3). I got the platinum trophy, but the game isn't 100%. I've completed the "Master Thief Sprint" in a couple of levels. I've also unlocked additional artistic content.

I wanna know if complete the game to 100% will give me something special. Artistic content doesn't interest me and I don't really want to put more time into the "Master Thief Sprint" challenges if there is nothing else at the end, other than artistic content.

Comment: They remade Sly for the PS3? :O

Comment: Yes! Including playstation move and 3d support. Also remaster in high definition. The game is called Sly Collection in US and Sly trilogy in Europe. http://us.playstation.com/games-and-media/games/the-sly-collection-ps3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of extra movies you get when completing all pages of the book and completing the time trials (master thief runs). Aside from that there's the Japanese opening you unlock by completing the game, that's pretty much it.

Comment: In addition to these, completing the Master Thief Sprint gives you the "Director's Commentary" for that level.